# Converting files containing many JSON to List of maps in scala

Tags: json, scala

Suppose I have a file:

JsonsFile.json

```
{"key1":"value11","key2":"value12","key3":"value13"}
{"key1":"value11","key2":"value12","key3":"value13"}
{"key1":"value11","key2":"value12","key3":"value13"}
```

It may have variable number of Jsons.
How can I get List of Maps from this file?
I would like to access elements like list(i)("key2")

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of scala libraries that process json, but I'm partial to [json4s](http://json4s.org). this can easily parse json into scala, but the direct result isn't a map. If your json records posses a regular format (as your example suggests) then I would recommend something like this

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import scala.io.Source

case class Record(key1:String, key2:String, key3:String)
implicit val format = DefaultFormats

 val records = Source.fromFile("JsonFile.json").getLines.map(parse(_).extract[Record]).toList
 \\ records will be a List[Record], with elements accessible like
 records(1).key2
```